# No cardinal between that of a finite set and the set plus one element

Tags: set-theory

How can we show that there is no set with cardinality strictly between a finite set S and the set $S \bigcup\{S\}$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, we say that $|A|\leq|B|$ iff there exists an injection from $A\to B$, and $|A|<|B|$ if $|A|\leq|B|$ and there is no bijection between $A,B$.

Suppose there exists some $X$ such that $S\to X\to S\cup\{S\}$ is a sequence of strict injections. We know that $f:S\to X$ is not a bijection, so there exists some $x\in X$ such that there is no $s\in S$ where $f(s)=x$. So, we can construct an injection $g:S\cup\{S\}\to X$ given by $g(s)=\begin{cases}x&s=S\\f(s)&s\neq S\end{cases}$. This, by C-S-B, shows there exists a bijection between $S\cup\{S\},X$. This is a contradiction.

Note that I haven't used $S$ being finite, since the claim doesn't require it.